# "Не местный" в паре с "местным" - слитно?

Tags: орфография

> Потому что в новой команде, состоящей из местных и неместных
>   наемников, в какой-то момент ружьё может быть обращено против тебя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от автора. Если он имеет в виду неместных=пришлых(приезжих), то слитно, если важно отрицание, что они местные, - раздельно.

Я бы предпочла слитное написание. На Ворд не обращайте внимания, если подчёркивает, в нём программа учитывает только основные правила, а когда какие-то варианты, он не умеет выбирать.